How do I pass parameters to a callable firebase cloud function in Java android
When I call the firebase function inside my java code it sends { '0': '' } as the parameters instead of the actual data. I've tries changing it so it only sends a single token instead of several, but it only sends empty parameters
Java Code fcmTokens is a List
FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> fcmTokens = new ArrayList<>();
        fcmTokens.add("test");
        data.put("fcmTokens", fcmTokens); // List of FCM tokens
        data.put("title", "test"); // Notification title
        data.put("body", "test"); // Notification body
        
        mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("sendCustomNotification")
                .call(data)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Notification sent successfully
                        Log.d("FCM", "Notification sent successfully");
                    } else {
                        // Handle errors
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.e("FCM", "Error sending notification", e);
                        }
                    }
                });

This is the firebase function code. It always throws an error
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

// Cloud function to send notification to multiple users
exports.sendCustomNotification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // Extract parameters from the data object
  const { fcmTokens, title, body } = data;
  console.log(data);
  // Check if fcmTokens is an array and contains tokens
  if (!Array.isArray(fcmTokens) || fcmTokens.length === 0) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "invalid-argument",
      "The fcmTokens array must be provided and non-empty."
    );
  }
//rest of the code
}

The parameter section of the data as shown in the console.log reads { '0': '' }

How did you observe that "it sends { '0': '' }"?  Also note that we can't see the values of the variables you're providing in data, so we aren't able to reproduce the problem.  Please edit the question to include more detailed debugging information, as well as more specific instructions on how to reproduce the issue.  We should be able to take your code and instructions to observe the same result.

@DougStevenson Thank you for the advice, I added the changes you recommended

So which line of code sends { '0': '' }"?
